# How to extract substrings with sscanf?

Tags: c

I have a file where lines have a similar format as shown below:

```
id: 1   address: tcp://localhost:8101
id: 2   address: tcp://128.134.59.1:8102
```

Now, for each line I want to extract everything starting from tcp, until the end of the line.
I tried reading the file one by one and using sscanf for that, but it seems my pattern 
matching is wrong as it never matches. What's the proper way to match the substring 
starting with tcp and all the way until the end of the line?

```
  char **id = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (nodes + 1));
  for (size_t i = 0; i < nodes; i++) {
    char *inter_id = calloc(25, sizeof(char));
    if ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        if (1 != sscanf(line, "%(tcp:*)", inter_id)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: could not parse the address.\n");
        exit(1);
      }
    }
    id[i] = inter_id;

 }
 id[nodes] = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, assuming the number of spaces between `id`, number and `address...` is identical for each line.

```
int main() {
    FILE* file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    char buffer[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        int id;
        // The reading is below. %d refers to the number that will be stored in
        // the variable id. %s refers to the char sequence that will be stored in
        // the memory pointed by buffer.
        fscanf(file, "id: %d   address: %s\n", &id, buffer);
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

The `file.txt` contains two lines:

```
id: 1   address: tcp://localhost:8101
id: 2   address: tcp://128.134.59.1:8102
```

and the program outputs:

```
tcp://localhost:8101
tcp://128.134.59.1:8102
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a mistake when copying, I update the question now. But, I guess same approach might work